# Что пишут в квадратные скобки?

Tags: c#

Очень часто стал замечать такой синтаксис:

```
[STAThread]
```

Что это? Просто какой-то идентификатор в квадратных скобках в отдельной строке?
Для чего он используется?

Comment: Это атрибут (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) - дополнительные метаданные.

Answer (score 4):

#### Это атрибут.

Атрибуты в C# представляют специальные инструменты, которые позволяют встраивать в сборку дополнительные метаданные. Атрибуты могут применяться как ко всему типу (классу, интерфейсу и т.д.), так и к отдельным его частям (методу, свойству и т.д.). Основу атрибутов составляет класс System.Attribute, от которого образованы все остальные классы атрибутов.

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос ТС, не думаю что это сходит за ответ на заданный вопрос.

Comment: @LLENN это как раз самая важная часть ответа. А назначение конкретного атрибута есть в документации. Разве что ссылку добавить.